# Roots of a polynomial modulo some prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, roots

> Let $p$ be a prime number not dividing $x$, let $n>1$. Consider the equations
> $$\tag{1} x^n-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
> and
> $$\tag{2} x^n+1\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
> What is the meaning (or the implication) of saying that equation (1) **or** equation (2) has at most $1$ solution $x$ modulo $p$, counting multiplicity?

I know that such equations have at most $n$ solutions $x$ modulo $p$, counting multiplicity by a theorem of Lagrange. Here $n$ is not necessarily equal to 2.

Comment: The formulation is unclear. Do we consider both congruences seperately , or is the claim that for each $n$ at least one of the congruences has at most $2$ solutions ?

Comment: @Peter: The statement: is at least one of the statements.....

Answer (score 2):

If $x^n-1\equiv0\pmod{p}$ has at most one solution, it has precisely one solution, because $x=1$ is a solution. That it has no other solution means that $x=1$ is the only element of $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ of order dividing $n$. This in turn implies that $\gcd(n,p-1)=1$. Similar statements hold for the other equation.

Comment: I am asking if there is a relation between $x$ and $p$

Comment: Your question doesn't mention anything like that. In fact your question is quite vague. If you have a specific question then you should make that explicit.